# In app billing v3 - why I get DEVELOPER_ERROR when calling queryPurchases(skuID)?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I implemented inapp billing (subscriptions) and everything works properly - I am able to subscribe, I acknowledge subscription, and billing flow ends succesfully with OK status.

However, at start of my app I am performing check (from Google Play cache) whether I already made purchases - and I always get DEVELOPER_ERROR.

This is my code:

```
public void checkIfPurchased() {
        billingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(BillingResult billingResult) {
                if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                        Purchase.PurchasesResult alreadyPurchasedResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(SKU_ID);
                        List<Purchase> alreadyPurchased = alreadyPurchasedResult.getPurchasesList();
                        ...
                        // alreadyPurchasedResult = 5 = DEVELOPER_ERROR
                }
            }
    }
```

Why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `queryPurchases` accepts as parameter either `BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP` or `BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS` as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient.SkuType).

In your example it looks like you put the SKU ID of your subscription product.

Comment: I do not know how could I miss that! Thanks a lot